# Internet recovery fails with different error codes - macOS Catalina

Tags: catalina, install, recovery, internet-recovery

I tried performing an internet recovery (Catalina) on my MacBook Pro Mid 2012 and each time I get a different error, for example: `-2000f` and `-1005f`.

I have tried this with different WiFi connections. I also tried to use my phones hotspot (4G) and it downloads, but gets stuck at a white screen.

Furthest I got was 2 minutes remaining on installation.

Comment: Do you have access to another Mac? If so it might work better to download the installer on another Mac, create a USB installer there and use **that** on your MBP.

Comment: I do not have access. Tried downloading a dmg file of high sierra, tried catalina and then mounting with terminal etc etc always gets stuck and fails.

Comment: Another possibility—how's your bandwidth quality?

Comment: Tried different connections with similar outcomes, then it stopped even starting and I got errors etc.